# Vue.JS authenticate SPA using laravel 5.8 API on a different domains

Tags: authentication, vue.js, jwt, laravel-5.8

I'm working on a SPA having 2 different domains: www.domain.org for frontend (vue.js) and api.domain.org (Laravel 5.8) for backend.

For auth I use JWT (with tymon/jwt-auth) having on frontend this:

```
    const token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;

    const body = {
        pId: pId,
        tId : tId,
    }

    const options = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        }
    };
    return Repository.post(`${resource}/lineup`, body, options)
```

This repository is a custom axios script I use.

**Backend test controller**:

```
  $token = $request->header('Authorization');
  echo "1) User: ";
  print_r(auth()->user());

  try {
      $user = auth()->userOrFail();
        print_r($user);
    } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\UserNotDefinedException $e) {

        echo "<br><br>ERROR - ".$e->getMessage();
    }
```

**Result**:

> Token: Bearer SL5phmp5QhTvytQM9Q4zh7rlgGoR1IuyYKj7kJQb
>
> 1) User: empty
>
> ERROR - An error occurred

**Test 2 Controller**:

```
 return response()->json(auth()->user());
```

**Result**:

> {"error":"Unauthorized"}

Can you help me to authorize API?

Comment: Because your frontend lives on a different domain then laravel, laravel won't inject a csrf-token into a meta tag of your index.html. I would use a jwt library like [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) or [passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport) for auth. Both of these libraries have middlewares that validate the token.

Comment: Thanks, LLai, I'm using jwt-auth. I have updated my question but it doesn't work...

Comment: Instead of passing a csrf token in you will instead pass a jwt. The flow is something like; user hits login route with email & password -> laravel returns jwt to user -> user hits an authenticated route with the jwt -> laravel authenticates jwt and processes request

Comment: That's right! Now I'm testing a get request passing jwt as ?token=xxxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz but I'm not authorized. My workflow is: Login using credential, I got the jwt and I store it in localStorage, then I do a get request using t this jwt but I got the error. I'm still using 2 different domains www for request and api for respond

Comment: Have you configured config/auth.php as described by the [docs](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/)?

Comment: yes: api and users are same as   'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

Comment: Do your authenticated routes have the `jwt.auth`? This middleware is the piece that looks for the token and determines if its vaid

Comment: I got!!!  So sorry LLai... I checked the JWT and I saw it was expired! With a new one, it works perfectly with your previous fixing.   Thanks a lot for your time! You were very helpful!

Comment: glad i could help!

Comment: For your experience; how is the best way to store jwt client side? I'm using LocalStorage during the test but maybe session is much more secure. What do you think about?

Comment: I have used localstorage in the past. Localstorage is vunerable to XSS attacks while session is vunerable to CSRF attacks. It depends on what security you want to put in place